# iPhone: Why do I need self.<> in viewDidUnload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I heard from people that you should use self in viewDidUnload. For instance, this is good:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
   self.object = nil;
   self.object2 = nil
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{ 
    object = nil;
    object2 = nil;
}
```

Is there a difference between the 2? And what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference. The code that is generated by @synthesize will call release on the references to the objects you have before setting the new value. A call to self.object = nil will effectively both release the reference and set it to nil. Without the self it will just set the reference to nil.

Comment: I should add that using self.object is accessing the reference via a property, while using object is accessing the reference directly via a field.

Answer (score 3):

What is almost the same as your second example is this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{ 
    [object release]; object = nil;
    [object2 release]; object2 = nil;
}
```

Note they are not quite the same - if you had defined a custom getter/setter, or had KVC observers set up around one of those properties the `self.object = nil` would trigger them, whereas the straight [`object release]` above would not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `self` eliminates ambiguity.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    id object = @"whatever";

    object = nil; // This refers to the local variable above
    self.object = nil; // This refers to the setter of the ivar belonging to the class
}
```

Another thing to watch out for is if you have the variables synthesized (meaning if you tell the compiler to generate getter & setter automatically), `self.object` will invoke the getter/setter, while simply `object` refers to the actual ivar. To prevent this ambiguity when accessing ivar vs calling the setter, you can write something like this:

```
self->object = nil; // This refers to the ivar object, not the getter/setter

// Or

@synthesize object = _object; // With this, you refer to the ivar as _object

// Then somewhere else
_object = nil; // This refers to the ivar
object = nil; // Compile error, undeclared identifier
self.object = nil; // This refers to the setter
```

According to Cocoa coding guidelines, we should avoid using underscores in naming variables though. So personally, if I really need to access the ivar directly (for example, when you are overriding the setter), I prefer using `->`.

Comment: No, that's not it.  Using `self->object = ...` would refer to the ivar, using `self.object = ...` is basically `[self setObject:...]`.  Huge difference, since the former (what you're saying) is just assignment, the latter is using a setter method that may assign, retain, or copy the value being set.

Comment: "The second method is no longer recommended by Apple."  What?

Comment: @nil I've corrected my first few statements but the first code snippet is still correct, I've verified this. Regarding the underscore, Apple's coding guideline stated this "Avoid the use of the underscore character as a prefix meaning private, especially in methods. Apple reserves the use of this convention. Use by third parties could result in name-space collisions".

Comment: The problem is that your explanation makes it sound as though _properties_ are discouraged.  Your answer is poorly worded enough that you could seriously misinform someone new to Objective-C and convince them that properties are bad, ignoring that it was at first completely wrong.  Additionally, using -> instead of properties is _bad_, as properties handle memory management for you, whereas just assigning something to an ivar leaves you open for problems (e.g., memory leaks or assigning soon-to-be-autoreleased objects).

Comment: The wording is better, but I still take issue with you suggesting the use of `->object = ...` (simple assignment) over `.object = ...` (properties).  That sort of thing is likely to harm you and others when coding in Objective-C as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @nil No, I am not recommending accessing the ivar directly. Let me clarify (again :))

Comment: Note that `object = nil;` will *never use the setter*.